# error when reshaping array with prime dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to reshape an array with 1501 (waveform) to (3,500) , but it complains as follow. please, help me to solve this problem.

```
x = np.array(x_train[2])
print(x.shape)
y = np.reshape(x, (int(len(x) / 500), 500))
print(y.shape)
```

Here is the output:

```
(1501,)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1501 into shape (3,500)
```

Comment: Surely, what you want is not possible. An array is always fully rectangular and the number of elements does not change. You must first remove the extra element.

Comment: How do you want to handle the number of elements? If you can explain that, I can tell you how to do it.

Comment: Also, `int(len(x)/500)` -> `len(x) // 500`

Comment: I want the final number of elements to be (3,500)

Comment: x dimension is 1501

Comment: @Badr. You need to make that clear in the question.

Comment: You do understand that 500 * 3 = 1500, not 1501?

Comment: You have 1,501 elements. You want to create a thing that stores 3 rows of 500 elements each. That, by definition, can only store 1,500 elements. Which one do you want to discard?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think the last element is the least important element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to view your data in chunks of 500, but it does not have a multiple of 500 elements, you need to truncate or pad it first. Let's say you are going with truncation here, since you have a wave-form and that last element is probably a repeat that will throw off your FFT anyway.

In that case, you can view less of the data in the buffer, then reshape however you want:

```
y = x[:(x.size // 500) * 500].reshape(-1, 500)
```

The nice thing here is that if your data is arranged somewhat sanely in memory, it will not make a copy, but return a contiguous view into the original buffer.